# Global DataTemplate in dll

Tags: wpf, resources, datatemplate

Extending the following question:
[WPF ListBoxItem events never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281282/wpf-listboxitem-events-never-called/51281750#51281750)

I moved the DataTemplate into a globally defined DataTemplate. But the defined look never appears.

I think I found the reason, the whole project is a dll. And the App.xaml is never called.

```
<ResourceDictionary>

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Styles/LookAndFeel.xaml" />

    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

is the first step (App.xaml)

The LookAndFeel.xaml contains the "link" to the DataTemplate:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/MySubFolder/MyDataTemplate.xaml" />
```

There's no building error, the application starts fine, but the layout defined in the DataTemplate is never used.

Just to verify, it's not a definition problem I copied the DataTemplate into the UserControl.Resources - works fine.

But how can I define it globally?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If none references App.xaml, the ResourceDictionary with the DataTemplate won't be used.

Comment: Excellent analysis. And can you help me out with a solution, please?